# How to avoid relational query to show 404?

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is a simple one... in Laracasts, I learned to do this to return all the articles matching a tag... if the tag exists, it works well even if there are no articles associated with it.  However if the tag does not exist in the tags table, it shows a 404 not found page.  My code will test after the query if there were articles found, so I just want to pass the query.

```
$articles = Tag::where('tag',request('tag'))
    ->firstOrFail()
    ->articles;
```

This gives the 404 not found page.

```
$articles = Tag::where('tag',request('tag'))
    ->first()
    ->articles;
```

This returns an error "Trying to get property 'articles' of non-object".

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to deubg the problem? Why not inspect whatever `first()` returns before using it?

Comment: OK @NicoHaase, do you mean removing "->articles" from the query and testing the result and only if there is something continue?  I understand the principle but if I get something how do I continue?

Comment: That depends on how you change your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do the query on the article model using the relation belongsTo to Tag

```
$tag = request('tag');
$articles = Article::whereHas('tag', function($query) use($tag) {
               $query->where('tag', $tag);
            })->get();
```

then you will get either an empty collection if the tag doesnt exist or the articles of the tag.